# How should I build a GWT application to a WAR file

Tags: gwt, ant, war

I have a GWT application that I need to deploy from a WAR file. I've got it kinda working using export to WAR option in Eclipse but after I deploy all of images in the application just show as missing image icon, and besides when we have multiple developers it is not nice to build from IDE this way.

I am looking for if there is a best way to script the build process that people have found (hopefully with an example) such as an Ant xml or any other GWT specific tools?

Answer (score 6):

This tutorial provides step by step instructions for writing an ant script to build the war file including GWT specific compile steps and where/how to package static resources such as images.

http://www.rubiconred.com/blog/build-package-a-gwt-app-to-war-using-ant/

Comment: unfortunately the tutorial you are naming isn't available anymore: 
"Sorry!
The page you are looking for has either moved or does not exist."

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the [GWT maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/).

If you're new to GWT or Maven, you might want to first read the [GWT documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/overview.html) and get more familiar with Maven by reading at least its [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/webtoolkit/overview.html) or by reading the [online reference book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html).